# Analytically finding minimum eigenvalue of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization

Is there a way to find the minimum eigenvalue of a matrix **analytically**? (I know that the usual way of finding the eigenvalues is the characteristic polynomial).

One definition of the minimum eigenvalue is

$$
\min_{\,\,\,x\\x\neq 0} \frac{\|A x\|^2}{\|x\|^2}
$$

For the simple matrix `[ 0 1 ; -2 -3 ]` I tried to find the smallest eigenvalue analytically by naming the x-vector components $x_1$ and $x_2$ and having $D = ((-2x_1 -3 x_2)^2 + x_2^2)/(x_1^2+x_2^2)$. From this I obtain the gradient $\frac{\partial D}{\partial x_1}$, $\frac{\partial D}{\partial x_2}$ and set it to zero solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Surely enough, this system of equations does not have a solution.

Comment: For an eigenvector $x$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, $x^TAx=\lambda\lVert x\rVert^2$. So it would seem that you need to divide that expression by $\lVert x\rVert^2$ before taking the min in order to find $\lambda$.

Comment: You are right. I added the normalization but the system does not have a solution either. I will update my question.

Comment: In the most recent edit you replaced $x^TAx$ with $\lVert Ax\rVert^2$. These are not the same. $\lVert Ax\rVert^2$ is the same as $x^TA^TAx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "definition" of minimum eigenvalue has several problems. For one thing, it would imply that every matrix has a real and positive eigenvalue, which is not true in general. 
Also, dont' forget a simple sanity check: your matrix property should apply for a $1\times 1$ matrix... and it clearly doesn't.

What you actually mean, I guess, is : if $M$ is hermitian and positive definite (which implies that its eigenvalues are real and positive), then letting $\lambda_1$ be its smallest eigenvalue, [we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)

$$\lambda_1 = \min_{x \ne 0} \frac{x^t M x }{x^t x} $$

Further, if we [decompose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) $M=A^t A$ the above gives

$$\lambda_1 = \min_{x \ne 0} \frac{x^t A^t A x }{x^t x} =\min_{\,\,\,x\\x\neq 0} \frac{\|A x\|^2}{\|x\|^2}$$

But, bear in mind, here $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, not of $A$.

To answer the question in the title: there cannot be a general analytical procedure for computing the smallest eingenvalue of a matrix, because the problem maps to finding the smallest root of a polinomial, and for degrees five and above there's no analytical procedure (in the usual sense of the expression) for doing that ([Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem))

On the other side, if the matrix is $2\times 2$, then it's [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula). But you would't use the Rayleigh quotient for that. This is only useful for computing numerically the smallest (or biggest) eigenvalue, by an [iterative method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

Comment: Rayleigh-Ritz theorem does not require the matrix to be positive definite. Being Hermitian is enough.